# Redefining selector to be used in a different way for the rest of the code

Tags: html, css

Supposing I have 20 p tags in my html code, I want 10 to be red and 10 be green. How would I do this in with a link tag in my html code to css stylesheet?

I'm a complete beginner learning from codeacademy so please use beginner terms for me to understand.

Comment: Please post example code of the 20 `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a class to them and set the css for that class to red or green however you want.

CSS File:

```
.primary {
    background-color: red;
}

.secondary {
    background-color: green;
}
```

HTML File:

```
<p class="primary">This content will be red</p>
<p class="primary">This content will also be red</p>
...
<p class="primary">This is my 10th red paragraph</p>

<p class="secondary">This content will be green</p>
...
<p class="secondary">This is my 10th green paragraph</p>
```

In the CSS file, you use the period (`.`) to signify a class. `.primary` is a selector for a class with the name `primary`.

After the selector, you can specify the attributes you want for any HTML element that matches that selector. The `background-color` attribute will set the background color.

Then we just have to modify the `class` attribute of each `p` tag to use the new classes we've created. This happens in the HTML document itself.

(Note: I called the classes `primary` and `secondary` instead of `green` and `red` so that you could later change the actual colors and not have the code look super confusing. Just a best practice thing with CSS in general)

(Also note: you can specify multiple classes for an HTML element by separating them with spaces. This doesn't make sense in this particular example (and isn't required), but if you need to in the future, you can have something like:

```
<p class="foo bar">this content will have styles from CSS class "foo" applied, and also from CSS class "bar"</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way , for example , using :nth:child()  selectors

```
p:nth-child(2), p:nth-child(3) {
    background: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: in this case :nth-child(2n), nth-child(3n) no?

Answer (score 0):

Use two css class (red and green) for red and green color in your stylesheet and call that class to your expected body text

**CSS:**

```
<style>
p a.green{color:green;
}

p a.red{color:red;
}
</style>
```

**HTML:**

```
<body>
<h4>Red p tag Text with a link tag</h4>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>
<p><a href="#" class="red">Your Text</a></p>

<h4>Green p tag Text with a link tag</h4>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
<p ><a href="#" class="green">Your Text</a></p>
</body>
```

Let me know your thoughts and feedback, thanks.